# Custom JsonConverter is failing after changing the ContractResolver in the default settings

Tags: c#, json.net

I've made a custom JsonConvert for NewtonSoft JSON... fully tested and working fine for some time now. But than someone said the properties need to be camelCased instead of PascalCased.

So, ok... I changed the NamingStrategy in my default settings.

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>  new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new StringEnumConverter(),
        new MessageEnvelopJsonConverter(PayloadTypes.GetMappings())
    },
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
```

And sure enough, the output works fine... no surprise there; the converter only uses read to ensure the correct implementation of an interface property, but has no write implementation.

Getting my version information now fails, the GetValue now no longer finds the property.

```cs
private int GetMessageVersion(JObject jObject)
{
    JToken versionToken = jObject.GetValue(nameof(MessageEnvelop.Version));

    if (versionToken is null)
    {
        throw new MandatoryPropertyMissingException(nameof(MessageEnvelop.Version));
    }

    return versionToken.Value<int>();
}
```

I used `JObject.Load` with the reader from the converter to create the used JObject and so I assumed this would ensure the translation of this naming convention... wrong assumption.

How can I make my converter use the correct naming strategy, and thus more resilient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JObject.GetValue(String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_GetValue.htm) is case sensitive, so if you just want to mimic the serializer's ordinal case insensitivity, you can call [`JObject.GetValue(String, StringComparison)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_GetValue_1.htm):

```
JToken versionToken = jObject.GetValue(nameof(MessageEnvelop.Version), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

That should be sufficient to handle naming differences due to camel casing, but if you want to handle more general naming changes, you may use Json.NET's own [contract information](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract.htm) to determine the JSON property name from the underlying .NET property name using the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueByUnderlyingName<T>(this JObject jObject, IContractResolver resolver, Type type, string underlyingName)
    {
        if (!resolver.TryGetJsonPropertyNameByUnderlyingName(type, underlyingName, out var jsonName))
            throw new ArgumentException(underlyingName);
        
        JToken versionToken = jObject.GetValue(jsonName);

        if (versionToken is null)
            throw new MandatoryPropertyMissingException(underlyingName);

        return versionToken.Value<T>();
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetJsonPropertyByUnderlyingName(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type, string underlyingName, out JsonProperty property) =>
        TryGetJsonPropertyByUnderlyingName(resolver, type, underlyingName, false, out property);

    public static bool TryGetJsonPropertyByUnderlyingName(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type, string underlyingName, bool exact, out JsonProperty property)
    {
        resolver = resolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resolver));
        
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        
        property = null;
        foreach (var p in contract.Properties)
        {
            if (p.UnderlyingName == underlyingName)
            {
                property = p;
                return true;
            }
            if (property == null && string.Equals(p.UnderlyingName, underlyingName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                property = p;
            }
        }
        return property != null;
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetJsonPropertyNameByUnderlyingName(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type, string underlyingName, out string jsonName) =>
        TryGetJsonPropertyNameByUnderlyingName(resolver, type, underlyingName, false, out jsonName);
    
    public static bool TryGetJsonPropertyNameByUnderlyingName(this IContractResolver resolver, Type type, string underlyingName, bool exact, out string jsonName)
    {
        if (resolver.TryGetJsonPropertyByUnderlyingName(type, underlyingName, exact, out var p))
        {
            jsonName = p.PropertyName;
            return true;
        }
        jsonName = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use it, inside [`JsonConverter<T>.ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1_ReadJson.htm), pass in `serializer.ContractResolver` for the `resolver` argument, and `objectType` as the `type` argument like so:

```
var version = jObject.GetValueByUnderlyingName<int>(serializer.ContractResolver, objectType, nameof(MessageEnvelop.Version));
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkivGn).